# MySQL: help designing tables for storing variable numbers of identical form lists

Tags: mysql, database-design

i'm ingesting JSON dumps of a client's form, which itself contains data from sub-forms.  so i have fields of data like 'username' and then blocks of form data that may or may not contain data.  the portion that concerns me looks like this:

```
"instruction1"=>true,
"instructionID1"=>1234,
"instructionInfo1"=>"blah blah",
"instructionReqs1"=>"bleh bleh",
"instructionDue1"=>1970-01-01,
...
```

this section repeats 14 more times `(eg. 'instruction2'=>false, &c)`.  each block either has content or it doesn't, but each record has 15 total as **part** of the overall record to be stored.  i am stumped as to how best to store this.  right now, trying to just blunt-force-trauma this thing gives me this error when i try to add the 15th block:

> Failed to add recordRow size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

and since i don't want to clone this whole thing (and everything else) over to a new instance of MariaDB (unless it is absolutely the only way out of this), the `innodb_page_size=64k` fix isn't viable.

i can't help but stare at this and say "this chunk should be a table", but if i made a table for it, how it would be structured to only store information, not empty fields (eg. 'instruction1xxx' thru 'instruction6xxx' and nothing beyond because they're empty), and then reference this back to the parent record in a way that i can retrieve it all to a dashboard.

*huff* *puff* *wheeze*

i have perused other responses to vaguely similar questions and MongoDB is not an option here because of the rest of the production stack itegration.

i hope this makes sense and i can get some clear eyes on this.  let me know if you need something more to clarify.

TIA.

Comment: Parse the data and turn each value into a row in the table.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It sounds like you have multiple JSON columns.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple key-value table.

```
CREATE TABLE formdata (
    client_id INT(11), // foreign key to client table
    name VARCHAR(128),
    value VARCHAR(1024)
);
```

Then each item in the JSON would be a row in the table.

```
client_id   name            value
1           instruction1    true
1           instructionID1  1234
1           instructionInfo1 blah blah
...
```

Comment: so then in the actual report record, i'd only keep the client_id from the instruction table (or what you're calling formData)?  how does that get retreived?  forgive me, i don't know where you're getting 'client' from and it appears to be referencing two places. i think i understand, though.  this might be simpler than i was expecting, thus overshooting the mark in my original design...  lemme see if i can grok this and get back to you.  thanks for the speedy response!  wow!  :D

Comment: You said this was part of a client's form. I assume you have multiple clients, and they each have forms, so you need to identify which client the form data comes from.

Comment: It doesn't come from the JSON itself, but from somewhere else in your application that knows which client this JSON is related to.

Comment: ok.  forgive my tired brain.  :P  here's how i see it in my head: the record of the client's form stores the foreign key to the instructions table.  if the record has 10 instructions, then 10 rows in the instructions table have the same key.  is that correct?  and we're not worrying about unique entries here either because some reports have *some* identical instructions; meaning the names and values won't always be unique

Comment: yep.  okay.  i got it.  i was waaaay overthinking this.  thank you @Barmar!  it was so simple...